# Programmatic subscription to changes of shared Word document?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, ms-word, office-addins

You can see changes made by other collaborators in real-time on an open Word document shared on SharePoint. Is there an event raised for these that you can subscribe to in a JS add-in?

Alternatively, can you subscribe to changes made to a Word document hosted on SharePoint in a .net application?

Edit: I see that you can do the latter at a file level using the SharePoint REST API.

Edit 2: I am pretty sure you cannot subscribe to the real-time collaboration changes programmatically. In addition to using the SharePoint REST API, you could use MS Graph API. I am not sure either provide any sort of granularity about changes within a file though, or just tell you which file has been changed.

Comment: I am currently doing some research on this issue, will let you know as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research and testing, when someone shares a Word document with you, you can **open the document in a Web browser**. If anyone else is working on the document, you'll see their presence and the changes they're making. In other words is real-time collaboration.

Here is a document for reference: [Collaborate on Word documents with real-time co-authoring](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/collaborate-on-word-documents-with-real-time-co-authoring-7dd3040c-3f30-4fdd-bab0-8586492a1f1d)

Comment: Yes, thanks, that was what I was referring to when I said you could see changes made by other collaborators in real-time on an open Word document. However, what I was asking about was whether you can subscribe to these events programmatically. So an event handler gets fired when an incoming change is received. From what I have found, I do not think that you can.